# php get matching keys between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect, array-key

What is the best way to get the matching keys between two associative arrays:

```
Array (
    [array_1] => Array (
        [abc] => 111
        [def] => 222
    ),
    [array_2] => Array (
        [ghi] => 995
        [jkl] => 996
        [mno] => 997
    )
)
```

and

```
Array (
    [array_1] => Array (
        [123] => 111
        [345] => 222
    ),
    [array_2] => Array (
        [123] => 995
        [432] => 996
        [345] => 997
    ),
    [array_3] => Array (
        [456] => 995
        [345] => 996
        [234] => 997
    )
)
```

I would like an array to be returned containing only the values: `array_1` and `array_2`.

`array_intersect` doesn't really work here neither will array_intersect_key as it will return the child array

I want this as a result:

```
array('array_1','array_2')
```

since these are the keys that match

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: what exactly to you want as result? please update your post with expected result (array) manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$theListOfKeysWotIWant = array_keys(
    array_intersect_key(
        $array1,
        $array2
    )
);
```